# Match where does not begin with

Tags: c#, regex

I currently have the following regex

```
(?!\(\) => )test\(.*,.*\)
```

But I would only like it to match

```
test("Test 1", () { expect(1, equals(1)); });
```

And not

```
test(test, () { expect(test, "Test3"); }) )
```

from the following text

```
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';

main() {

  testExecuter("fileName", test, () => $0 );
  test("Test 1", () { expect(1, equals(1)); });

  var tests = ["Test2", "Test3"];

  for (var test in tests) {
    testExecuter("fileName", test, () => test(test, () { expect(test, "Test3"); }) );
  }
}
```

I am using regexpal.com to test it for some reason the part of the regex saying not to begin with () => is not working

Comment: Are you sure this is C#?  `import` is not something I normally associate with C# and the formatting looks more like Java...

Comment: @Tim: That's the text he's using the regex on, not the program that runs the regex...

Comment: @TimPietzcker - Ah...should have read the question closer.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of what it's matching that you don't want it to match?

Comment: @ap OP says that in the question.

Comment: @DavidG so he does - I misread a part of it. SO after naps is dangerous ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a *lookahead* assertion when you should be using a *lookbehind* assertion:

```
(?<!\(\) => )test\(.*,.*\)
```

After all, `"test(test, ()..."` does in fact not *begin with* `"() => "` - it is *preceded* by it, hence you need to look "behind" the current position.